# How to disable the URL in my application not to change manually

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to disable the URL in my application not to change manually.

Ex: I have index.aspx page. in that I have one button called Create. when I click I going to Create.aspx page.

based on some validation I am disabling Create Button on Index page. I am able to do that.

what is my problem is when I manually change the URL I am going there is there any way that we can disable the URL from manuall?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the disable logic or where this url is pointed to, I'd say this is the job for a custom action filter.

Here's an example of a custom validation filter:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //the base will just do the default behavior

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            //...if(same eval logic for button)==true
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(<url>); //or RedirectToRoute(...
        }
    }
```

Then in your controller's action method, apply the attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable when the user can view the create page.

```
Session["Create"]=true;
```

When they get to the create.aspx, check that session variable. If it's true, let them in, if not-put them to your index page.

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable when you click the "CreateButton" on index page.

```
//Code for your button on your index page

    Session["allowaccesstoCreatePage"]=1;
```

Check this session variable on your create.aspx page load

```
if(Session["allowaccesstoCreatePage"]==null)
{
Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this in the Page_Load event of Create.aspx or for better in the Page_Init event

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer == null) 
        Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
```